# Неправильная иконка сайта в верхней панели

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, favicon

Почему-то пропала старая иконка, и заменилась иконкой сайта ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

[image]

[image]

При этом, иконка в логотипе старая:

[image]

**UPD**: тем временем, иконка сайта "Русский язык" заменилась на иконку сайта "Russian Language", а иконка сайта "Russian Language" превратилась в какое-то облачко. Это *точно* не ребрендеринг :)

Comment: А я думал, это ребрендинг такой :)

Comment: М-м... не наблюдаю. Видимо, у меня в кэше ещё нормальная версия и скоро это дойдёт и до меня.

Comment: @D-side Не могли бы вы сделать скриншоты нормальной версии, на память? :-)

Comment: Разумеется, [прошу сюда](http://i.imgur.com/VvShQra.png).

Comment: Сбросил кэш, но не вижу такой иконки ни в одном браузере.

Comment: Проверил в свежеустановленном в свежей ОС браузере, тоже не наблюдаю.

Comment: @D-side видимо потому что уже пофиксилось. Я тоже не наблюдаю теперь.

Comment: Утром такое у себя видел, сейчас уже нет.

Comment: Сейчас видел, нажал Ctrl+F5 - пофиксилось :)